# create subgroups for variable

Tags: r

I have received a data set about the ingredients of sweets of different brands, as well as information about prices in percent, sugar and profit in percent. The information on the ingredients are dummy variables, where 0 means that the characteristic is not present and 1 means that it is present. The other variables are numerical and represent the sugar content of a candy, the price of a product. Profit per Produt is a character variable. The goal is to select a statistical method to determine consumer preferences and to make a prognosis for a new product. I would like to implement the solution for this in R.

My goal is to split the variable "winpercent" into two subgroups.If the value > 43,078,911, winner, if the value < 43,078,911, loser. What would the solution look like in R?

dpt(rbind(head(Sweets.df, 10), tail(Sweets.df, 10)))

```
dput(rbind(head(Sweets.df, 10), tail(Sweets.df, 10)))
structure(list(competitorname = c("100 Grand", "3 Musketeers", 
"One dime", "One quarter", "Air Heads", "Almond Joy", "Baby Ruth", 
"Boston Baked Beans", "Candy Corn", "Caramel Apple Pops", "Tootsie Roll Juniors", 
"Tootsie Roll Midgies", "Tootsie Roll Snack Bars", "Trolli Sour Bites", 
"Twix", "Twizzlers", "Warheads", "WelchÕs Fruit Snacks", "WertherÕs Original Caramel", 
"Whoppers"), chocolate = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), fruity = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), caramel = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), peanutyalmondy = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), nougat = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), crispedricewafer = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L), hard = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), bar = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), pluribus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), sugarpercent = c(0.73199999, 
0.60399997, 0.011, 0.011, 0.90600002, 0.465, 0.60399997, 0.31299999, 
0.90600002, 0.60399997, 0.31299999, 0.17399999, 0.465, 0.31299999, 
0.546, 0.22, 0.093000002, 0.31299999, 0.186, 0.87199998), pricepercent = c(0.86000001, 
0.51099998, 0.116, 0.51099998, 0.51099998, 0.76700002, 0.76700002, 
0.51099998, 0.32499999, 0.32499999, 0.51099998, 0.011, 0.32499999, 
0.255, 0.90600002, 0.116, 0.116, 0.31299999, 0.26699999, 0.84799999
), winpercent = c("66.971.725", "67.602.936", "32.261.086", "46.116.505", 
"52.341.465", "50.347.546", "56.914.547", "23.417.824", "38.010.963", 
"34.517.681", "43.068.897", "45.736.748", "49.653.503", "47.173.229", 
"81.642.914", "45.466.282", "39.011.898", "44.375.519", "41.904.308", 
"49.524.113")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

```
Sweets.df <- read.csv("Sweets.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `winpercent` isn't numeric (notice the quotes around the numbers and `.`s as separators) so we'll first address that, then we'll create a new variable based on the values:

```
Lidl.df$winpercent = as.numeric(gsub(".", "", Lidl.df$winpercent, fixed = TRUE))
Lidl.df$result = ifelse(Lidl.df$winpercent > 43078911, "winner", "loser")
```